# How can I remove the border of a TextView item in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview, border

I have this bank info list for user to select a bank. I have set textview's background with a drawable file to replace system effect. However, it will show ***orange borders(system effect)*** around textview which looks terrible for me .I would like to give you guys some pictures, since my reputation is not enough, I'm really sorry about that.

**here is my xml file of listview's item:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bank_name"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_line" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bank_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="bank"
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@drawable/color_talk_item" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**here is the drawable file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/nomal"/>
</selector>
```

I've also tried to set `android:listSelector="@null"`in my listview. But it seems not work. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Edit:**
I think I've got 2 upvote for not have any picture or miss something. 
here is the link of the problem pciture.
https://plus.google.com/photos/106086983193067474741/albums/6152765738463306577

**Here is the main listview:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/no_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_title" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/bank_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollingCache="false" >
    </ListView>
</frameLayout>
```

Comment: "I would like to give you guys some pictures, since my reputation is not enough, I'm really sorry about that." You can upload image anywhere and put the link here.  And also put the XML code which contains listView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set listselector null you can do it like below :

in xml  `android:listSelector="#00000000"`

through coding : `myListView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0x0));`

Comment: This solved my problem. I wonder why set `android:listSelector="@null"` will not do the effect.